# java export to jar with user input

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I made a small program which takes a user input then get an output to a txt file.
The program runs without any problem in eclipse. Then i exported it as runnable jar file.
Now if I click the file, it just generates an empty txt file.
So is it possible to create a jar which takes user input? What did I do wrong?

Comment: You (and we) need more information. If there's no other way, start a command line prompt, runt he java program from there, and use `System.out.println()` to output debugging information. Common problems when going from eclipse to standalone are failure to include some resource files and an environment difference such as classpath or library availability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. What's going wrong? Who knows, there's not much detail here.

Taking a **wild** stab in the dark:

- You're on windows.
- You're double clicking it to start the app.
- You're asking for input via `System.in`.

On windows, an application has to declare whether they do command line stuff (show a black box) in the app itself. Therefore, only on windows, java.exe comes in two variants: java.exe and javaw.exe. The -w version is pre-declared to not take user input. The java.exe version will always show an ugly black box, even if the app takes no input or output. By default, javaw is used to open jar files, thus, you can't use System.in in that case.

There is no solution for the problem of 'make this app work if I double click it on windows' - in fact, there is no general solution to 'make it so that this jar file will run properly on any system I copy it to' - getting a functioning JVM is (since 10 years or so) no longer the responsibility of the user; it is your responsibility, you'd have to build an entire installer.

I presume you're still learning, in which case - hey, that's not the goal, right? Just.. open a dosbox (hit the windows key, type 'cmd', hit enter), and run your app as `java -jar myjar.jar` and all will be well. If you need to ship it, well, you can make a batch script that does that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this user input comes from the system input stream `System.in`.

It needs to run in a console/terminal/shell that provides an input stream.

For example, if you are running on linux, open a terminal and run this:

```
java -jar myprogram.jar
```

On Windows:

```
javaw -jar myprogram.jar
```